# how the expression *p++ and ++*p works differently

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a[2]={10,4};
    int *k;
    int *j; 
    j=a;
    k=j; 
    printf("j=%d,k=%d\n\n",*j,*k);
    *j++;
    ++*k;
    printf("j=%d,k=%d",*j,*k);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

> j=10 k=10
>   j=4 k=11

I thought that it should have same result but this is not the case.
I wished to ask what is causing this difference. I didn't got the reason behind it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two things going on here:

- The different semantics between prefix and postfix `++`;
- Different precedence of prefix and postfix operators.

Postfix operators have higher precedence than unary (prefix) operators, so the expression `*p++` is parsed as `*(p++)` - you're applying the `*` operator to the result of `p++`.  By contrast, the prefix `++` operator and unary `*` have the same precedence, so the expression `++*p` is parsed as `++(*p)` - you're applying the `++` operator to the result of `*p`.

Also remember that prefix and postfix `++` have slightly different behavior.  Both increment their operand as a side effect, but the *result* of postfix `++` is the current value of the operand, while the result of prefix `++` is the value of the operand plus 1.

Answer (score 3):

You need to dig out your operator precedence table.

`*p++` is evaluated as `*(p++)`

`++*p` is evaluated as `++(*p)`

The second one is due to the prefix `++` having the same precedence as pointer dereference `*` so *associativity* (which is from right to left for those operators) comes into play.

For completeness' sake, `*(p++)` dereferences the current value of `p`, and `p` is increased by one once the statement completes. `++(*p)` adds 1 to the data pointed to by `p`.

Comment: The associativity of unary and postfix operators is self-evident and practically irrelevant. `***p` could not possibly associate left-to-right as in `(((*)*)*)p` because that makes no sense. Likewise `a[i][j](z)` couldn't be `a([i]([j]((z))))`.   If you write a Yacc parser for these, you need no `%assoc` declaration: the ambiguity of that kind simply isn't there.  In C we just have to remember that the unary operators have a lower precedence than postfix, so  `op op op expr op op op` means `op op op (expr op op op)`.